# How to access data from .write() in opencascade.js

Tags: reactjs, opencascade

I'm trying to access my data from my exported step file in opencascade.js.

I used this example

https://github.com/donalffons/opencascade.js-examples

and updated the library.js like this to export a step-file:

```
  var writer = new openCascade.STEPControl_Writer_1();
  var progressRange = new openCascade.Message_ProgressRange_1();
  writer.Transfer(reader.OneShape(), openCascade.STEPControl_StepModelType.STEPControl_AsIs, true, progressRange);
  writer.Write("test.step")
```

no errors are thrown, but I dont know how to access the data now.

I updated this sandbox too:

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-platform-2gc274

the library.js can be found here:

src/demos/bottle - basic/library.js